# Setting a Text Box Value based on Report Viewer Parameter Value

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report Viewer object on my ASP.NET VB.NET Page and a Text Box.

I've figured out how to set the Report Viewer Parameters but how do I "Get" values that are already set?

For example I want to Set the Value of a Textbox on the ASP Page based on a ReportViewer Parameter. I can get the Parameter Name using:

```
For Each oParamInfo In ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters
        oParamInfo.Name
Next
```

But I can't figure out how to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do this in the expression for the Textbox in the rdl file. Check the Parameter value before deciding what value to output.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Numeric.Value = 1, "123", "ABC")
```